# JQuery Cookie.js Save cokkie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hi there i am using jquery cookie.js to store cookie.

I have search the code and with the cookie.js plugin it's working fine,
But i am having an issue that when i refresh the page the cookie automatically save and the popup does not display. When any user enter on the site a popup appear and the user must have to click the continue button to enter on the site,

I am basically not allowing user to enter on the site before clicking the continue button.

Here is my html code

```
<div id="popup-container">
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="popup-window">
  <div class="splash-bg">
    <h1>Are You Over 18? Click Continue if you are or return to previous 
      page</h1>
  <a type="button" class="close">Continue</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the js code i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
      jQuery('#popup-container a.close').click(function(){
          jQuery('#popup-container').fadeOut();
          jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
      });

      var visits = jQuery.cookie('visits') || 0;
      visits++;

      jQuery.cookie('visits', visits, { expires: 1, path: '/' });

      console.debug(jQuery.cookie('visits'));

      if ( jQuery.cookie('visits') > 1 ) {
        jQuery('#active-popup').hide();
        jQuery('#popup-container').hide();
      } else {
          var pageHeight = jQuery(document).height();
          jQuery('<div id="active-popup"></div>').insertBefore('body');
          jQuery('#active-popup').css("height", pageHeight);
          jQuery('#popup-container').show();
      }

      if (jQuery.cookie('noShowWelcome')) { jQuery('#popup-
      container').hide(); jQuery('#active-popup').hide(); }
    }); 

    jQuery(document).mouseup(function(e){
      var container = jQuery('#popup-container');

      if( !container.is(e.target)&& container.has(e.target).length === 0)
      {
        container.fadeOut();
        jQuery('#active-popup').fadeOut();
      }

    });
 </script>
```

Comment: don't check `> 1`. check an actual value, or if it's a number or an object

Comment: When someone refresh the page the cookie saved automatically i am looking for a solution that stops this happen ...

Comment: i have tried that but it din't work

Answer (score 0):

When you have number of cookies visits cookie may not be the first cookie in the cookie array so you have to try to get that cookie by using following both ways

```
jQuery.cookie('visits')

jQuery.cookie(' visits')
```

Comment: console.log(document.cookie) what you can see ?

Comment: i simply wants some condition to stop the automatic save by refreshing the page unless the user click the continue button ... here is the link where i get the code http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Cookie-Based-Modal-Popup-Plugin-For-jQuery-Popup-Window.html

Comment: Hi didi you able to fix your cookie issue ?